# Solving a recurrence equation with sum

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

In my algorithm analysis, I have the following recurrence equation:

> $T(n) = n \sum_{i=1}^{n}(T(n-i)) + c, T(0) = 1$

I want to solve this equation so that to construct big-O from it. I know that `T(n) = T(n-1) belongs to O(2^n)`, but I don't know how to simplify the sum part. Any hints or steps are much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "$T(n)=T(n-1)$ belongs to $O(2^n)?$"

Comment: from what I learn, the complexity with the the recurrence equation T(n) = T(n-1) can be upper bounded by O(2^n). but please, correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I still have no idea what you mean by "the recurrence equation $T(n)=T(n-1)\dots.$" The recurrence equaltion $T(n)=T(n-1)$ is triviallly $O(1)$ which is $O(2^n),$ but that doesn't seem like what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simplification I see:

$$ T_n = n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} T_i +c = nT_{n-1} + \frac{n}{n-1} (n-1)\sum_{i=0}^{n-2} T_i +c  = nT_{n-1} + \frac{n}{n-1} T_{n-1} +c = \frac{n^2}{n-1} T_{n-1} +c $$
Maybe someone can find an expression $T_n = f(n)$ which would be even better for the sake of complexity

Answer (score 0):

$$
T_n = n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}T_k+c\\
T_{n-1} = (n-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}T_k+c
$$

hence

$$
\frac{T_n}{n}-\frac{T_{n-1}}{(n-1)} = T_{n-1} -\frac{c}{n(n-1)}
$$

or

$$
T_n - \left(\frac{n^2}{n-1}\right)T_{n-1}=-\frac{c}{n-1}
$$

Which has as general solution

$T_n = C_0 n \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(2)}+c F(n)$

Comment: I had forgotten the constant $c$ ... My fault!